# Removing Consecutive Characters in each Iteration shows Unexpected error

Tags: java, string

How to remove Consecutive Characters at each Iteration..
Below is the screenshot that explains the question with more details

[image: Q1]

MySolution

1. Initially I checked whether there are any Consecutive characters.
   If yes,Then,remove all the consecutive characters and when there are no consecutive characters add the remaining characters to another String.
2. If no Consecutive Characters just simply increment it.

```
public static void print(){
    String s1="aabcccdee";  I have taken a sample test case
    String s2="";
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length();){
        if(s1.charAt(i)==s1.charAt(i+1)){
            while(s1.charAt(i)==s1.charAt(i+1)){
                i++;
            }
            for(int j=i+1;j<s1.length();j++){
                s2=s2+s1.charAt(j);
            }
        s1=s2;  
        }
        else
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Output Shown

```
An infinite Loop
```

Expected Output for the give sample is

```
bd
```

> Can Anyone guide me how to correct?

Comment: Don't use screenshots to describe your problem, type it out yourself please.

Comment: @YCF_L edited the code

Comment: can you share the all the inputs please i can't see the picture!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`String::replaceFirts`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with this regex `(.)\1+` which means matche any charater `(.)` which followed by itself `\1` one or more time `+` with empty.
In case you want to replace first by first you have to check the input, if after each iteration still contain more than one consecutive characters or not, in this case you can use [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) like this :

```
String[] strings = {"aabcccdee", "abbabba", "abbd "};
for (String str : strings) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1");

    // While the input contain more than one consecutive char make a replace
    while (pattern.matcher(str).find()) {
        // Note : use replaceFirst instead of replaceAll
        str = str.replaceFirst("(.)\\1+", "");
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
aabcccdee -> bd
abbabba   -> a
abbd      -> ad
```

Comment: I was waiting for a beautiful `replaceAll` solution ;-)

Comment: it return `abbd` @UsagiMiyamoto i think this is the expected result no?

Comment: I have just read that this should further be parsed to get rid of the `bb`

Comment: bb or bd @ScaryWombat the OP said `Expected Output for the give sample is bd`

Comment: Yes, for your sample it is correct, but how about for `input 3` ?

Comment: @YCF_L It should pass all test case.I have just taken the sample test case.Also what this regular expression mean (.)\\1+

Comment: sorry @ScaryWombat i can't see the picture politic of network can you please tell me what did you mean by input 3?

Comment: `abbabba` -> `aabba` -> `bba` -> `a`

Comment: although I am not sure why not `abbabba` -> `aaa` -> ``

Comment: this is correct @ScaryWombat `abbabba` should return empty in the end

Comment: you can check my solution now @ScaryWombat this can solve the problem of OP

Comment: @JalajChawla check my edit now it can solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

I had misread the question. The intent is to also remove the consecutive characters after each replacement. The below code does that.

```
private static String removeDoubles(String str) {
    int s = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        // If the current character is the same as the previous one,
        // remember its start position, but only if it is not set yet
        // (its value is -1)
        if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i - 1)) {
            if (s == -1) {
                s = i - 1;
            }
        }
        else if (s != -1) {
            // If the current char is not equal to the previous one,
            // we have found our end position. Cut the characters away
            // from the string.
            str = str.substring(0, s) + str.substring(i);
            // Reset i. Notice that we don't have to loop from 0 on,
            // instead we can start from our last replacement position.
            i = s - 1;
            // Finally reset our start position
            s = -1;
        }
    }
    if (s != -1) {
        // Check the last portion
        str = str.substring(0, s);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Note that this is almost 10 times faster than YCF_L's answer.

---

#### Original post

You are almost there, but you don't have to use multiple for loops. You just need one loop, because whether to remove characters from the string only depends on subsequent characters; we don't need to count anything.

Try this:

```
private static String removeDoubles(String s) {
    boolean rem = false;
    String n = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        // First, if the current char equals the next char, don't add the
        // character to the new string and set 'rem' to true, which is used
        // to remove the last character of the sequence of the same
        // characters.
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
            rem = true;
        }
        // If this is the last character of a sequence of 'doubles', then
        // reset 'rem' to false.
        else if (rem) {
            rem = false;
        }
        // Else add the current character to the new string
        else {
            n += s.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    // We haven't checked the last character yet. Let's add it to the string
    // if 'rem' is false.
    if (!rem) {
        n += s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Note that this code is on average more than three times faster than regular expressions.

Comment: It does produce Expected Output for this Case abbabba.

Answer (score 0):

consider this easier to understand code

```
    String s1="aabcccdee";  

    while (true) {
    rvpoint:            
        for (int x = 0; x < s1.length() -1; x++)
        {
            char c = s1.charAt(x);
            if (c == s1.charAt(x+ 1)) {
                s1 = s1.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
                continue rvpoint;  // keep looping if a replacement was made
            }
        }
        break;  // break out of outer loop, if replacement not found
    }

    System.out.println(s1);
```

**note**

This will only work for the first iteration, put into a method and keep calling until the sizes do not change

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static void print() {
   String s1 = "abcccbd"; // I have taken a sample test case
   String s2 = "";
   while (!s1.equals(s2)) {
      s2 = s1;
      s1 = s1.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "");
   }
   System.out.println(s1);
}
```